# Active Directory LDAP authentication Git Windows Server 2008

Tags: git, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to setup git through apache on a windows server. I'm using msysgit version 1.7.7.1-preview20111027. I've gotten most of it working but pushing over http and authenticating through Active Directory is an issue.

Here's my httpd.conf:

> <Directory />
>     Allow from All
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory C:/GitRepos>
>     AuthName "Git Repositories"
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthBasicProvider ldap
>     AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
>     AuthLDAPUrl ldap://server/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
>     AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=User,OU=someunit,DC=domain,DC=com"
>     AuthLDAPBindPassword password
>     AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
>     AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
>     Require ldap-group CN=ADGroup,OU=unit1,OU=unit2,DC=domain,DC=com
>     Satisfy any
> </Directory>
>
> SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/GitRepos
> SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
> # SetEnv REMOTE_USER $REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
> ScriptAliasMatch \
>         "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
>                 info/refs | \
>                     objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
>                         [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
>                         pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
>                 git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
>                 "C:/Program Files (x86)/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
>
> <LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
>     AuthName "Git Repositories"
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthBasicProvider ldap
>     AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
>     AuthLDAPUrl ldap://server/DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
>     AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=User,OU=someunit,DC=domain,DC=com"
>     AuthLDAPBindPassword password
>     AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
>     AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
>     Require ldap-group CN=ADGroup,OU=unit1,OU=unit1,DC=domain,DC=com
>     Satisfy any
> </LocationMatch>

If I uncomment:

> # SetEnv REMOTE_USER $REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER

I can push over http, but a user can type anything in for a password and the ldap authorization doesn't limit the repositories to just the one Active Directory group.

Are my settings incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I have succesfully made it over https, but its best working with ssh.

anyway I have some articles on russian:

- how to configure ssh with AD and to use with git: http://habrahabr.ru/post/130187/
- how to make https auth with AD. But I configured it to svn and its quite simple to make it with git: http://habrahabr.ru/post/73403/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this earlier thread may help:
[Is there a way to use Windows Authentication (Active Directory) for a Git server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329740/is-there-a-way-to-use-windows-authentication-active-directory-for-a-git-server)

It doesn't answer your exact question but may provide other avenues for using AD authentication.