# Active Directory support for Git Server using Redmine

Tags: git, active-directory, redmine

An earlier question about whether it was possible for Git to use Active Directory authentication included [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9070883/216440), by user [faken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605790/faken), which suggested Redmine was a good way of doing it.  By chance, one of my work colleagues had the previous day suggested including [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) when we implement Git so I'm interested.

My question is: How easy is it to set up Redmine and Git in this way?

The reason I ask is that at work there is an aversion to complex installation processes that require half a dozen or more components from different sources and a learning period of a couple of days.  Rightly or wrongly, such installations are seen as very brittle for two reasons:

1. Multiple dependencies on independent projects that may not necessarily play well together in future versions;
2. A lengthy learning and experimentation period needed to get the diverse components up and running, of the order of a day or two, which busy system administrators cannot afford.

Not trying to troll here but I know what my boss' first reaction would be when I show him the instructions linked to in faken's earlier answer above.  However, I don't want to judge a book by its cover and write Redmine off based on the first impression of that instruction page. I'd really like to be able to go to my boss and show him an answer that says something like: We've already done it, it wasn't painful, took about this long, these are the few things to watch out for.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: I would think about pushing a paid suite then, like Atlassian, or Github.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Jacob, but I don't think my boss will pay just to get AD integration with git.  I've currently got Git for Windows up and running out of the box, with username and email in the .gitconfig file.  AD integration is a nice-to-have on top of the basic functionality but not essential.

Comment: Well AD is just kerberos under the hood, so anything that supports kerberos realms will work. Apache for instance has a kerberos module that will work with modern browsers, or fallback to basic authentication. If redmine can defer to apache for authentication you might get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Git through HTTP you can easily use `SPNEGO` to protected your repos and if Redmine supports reading the `$REMOTE_USER` var you can have the webserver perform the authentication. `mod_auth_kerb` or `mod_auth_gss` serve this very well.

Comment: Not quite what I was asking but useful information nonetheless, if we decide to go down the Redmine route.  Thanks.